# Dynamically enable asp button based on datasource value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, button, templatefield

SOLVED: See my solution below!

using aspx with C# code behind.

I have the following code in a button in a item template in a gridview:

```
Enabled='<%# IIF(Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y","TRUE","FALSE") %>'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The name 'IIF' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the same error if I use "IF" rather than "IIF"

The full item template code is as follows:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button  ID="wrqst_need_ind_btn" runat="server" Text = "Create WR" 
                    onClientClick="javascript:popUp('popup_createWR.aspx')"  
                    Enabled='<%# IIF(Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y","TRUE","FALSE") %>'
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("dvc_nm") + "|" + Eval("data_orgtn_yr") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If I take the line out it works fine.

Seems to me like this should work...

EDIT: I am now using this:

```
Enabled='<%#Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" %>'
```

And geting this error:

The server tag is not well formed.

Thanks so much for your help!

Update:

I tried this:

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? Convert.ToBoolean(1) : Convert.ToBoolean(0) %>' and it ran!
```

But, every button was disabled. So I tried:

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? Convert.ToBoolean(1) : Convert.ToBoolean(1) %>'
```

and then every button was disabled. It seems that every time it is returning false... why?

SOLVED: See my solution below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, that ternary syntax is:

```
Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"
```

If you happen to be using VB.NET (it looks like you are not), use the `If` function.

```
If(Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y", "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

EDIT: It turns out that `==` here will not compare the string contents, but the string objects. So, instead, you must use `.Equals("Y")`. So, community-generated final answer is:

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind").Equals("Y") %>'
```

Comment: I'm getting an error converting string to bool... I'm trying a few different variations but i can't seem to get it...

Comment: my code is: Enabled='<%#Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE" %>'

Comment: I think you need a space before the "Eval" keyword. Also, I'm not sure if it's case-sensitive, but it should be "true" and "false".

Comment: stil getting the name error using the following code: Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? "true" : "false" %>' There is a space between the # and Eval and I made the true and flase lower case? Any other suggestions??? Thanks!

Comment: check off this as the answer because ChessWhiz should get the credit. However there is a minor technicality. You must use .Equals, not ==. I posted that change in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that worked!

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind").ToString().Equals("Y".ToString()) ? Convert.ToBoolean(1) : Convert.ToBoolean(0) %>'
```

Comment: Although as Chris noted this also works: Enabled='<%# Eval("wrqst_need_ind").Equals("Y") %>' Notice that you MUST have the .Equals or it will return false every time. (unless of course the objects are actually the same... but they are not)

Comment: I feel sad that you accepted your own answer, when it was really my answer that gave the solution to the original 'IIF' question. :)

Comment: wtf... i accepted your answer too... idk why it's not showing it... I was trying to give you credit and let other people know the answer that worked for me...

Comment: oh lol, guess you can't choose more than one answer as "the answer"... thats kinda silly, what if two people combined to give you the right answer? 
Well anyways, i checked your answer as the answer instead of mine...
Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: well i commented on your answer about the .Equals thing so others would see it. That so stupid, I should be able to mark two answers as the answer and have them both apear at the top so people can see the right answerS first...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about all the "Convert.ToBoolean(1)" stuff you've got going on. If you want true and false just write true and false (without quotes or it will be treated as a string).

eg. `Enabled='<%#Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" ? true:false %>'`

Of course as I type that it occurs to me that you don't *need* to use this kind of operator. the condition returns true or false anyway so the above simplifies to:

```
Enabled='<%#Eval("wrqst_need_ind") == "Y" %>'
```

Comment: ya not using true or false at all might have worked. However I tried not using quotes and I got some other error. I don't remeber what the error was I tried the other day. However, because the comparison is between two strings .Equals must be used or the expression will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the correct keywork is "if" in lowercase.

Comment: He's using VB, not C# :) `IIF` = "If and only if"

Comment: i'm not using vb. i'm using C#. Or at least that was my intention.

Answer (score 0):

In case it will help anyone else...

This style did **not** work for me:

```
(Eval("status").ToString()).Equals("Done")
```

but this style did work:

```
(Eval("status").ToString()).Contains("Done")
```